# ppl_detection package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I altered the launch file in the package and change the "find trainer" part to "find ppl_detection" . after this when i run the launch file. rviz etc open and I am able to c people clearly. but when I try the rosrun ppl_detection kinect_detect, it says segmentation fault and exits. can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11825/ppl_detection-package/) by [siddhu723](https://answers.ros.org/users/1166/siddhu723/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you'd better first check segmentation fault of `RViz` issue in this QA web site, separately from `ppl_detection`. In my environment it doesn't occur, and based on your tweak (changing package name) I'm now successfully running the people detection.

Environment: Ubuntu 11.04, `electric` all updated up to "important security" as of 12/1/2011.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0